# How can set these iptables rules to run at startup

Tags: scripts, firewall, iptables

I usually run my iptables rules whenever I login. From the terminal I type ;

```
sudo sh firewall.sh
```

Setting up my sister's computer, I want to give her some basic firewall protection. She wont be logging in as admin, just a standard account. How can I make a firewall script run everytime she logs in without her having to type in any password?

The script I wrote for my sister's computer contains ;

```
#!/bin/sh

modprobe ip_conntrack
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 --sport 32768:61000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

I've placed it in her home folder as firewall.sh and set it to be executable (right click on the file, and checking the "allow executing file as program" option in the permissions tab).

Running this script from the terminal as root works fine.

After typing ;

```
sudo sh firewall.sh
```

I typed into the terminal

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

and I get

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcpflags: FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:32768:61000 dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp spts:32768:61000 dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:32768:61000 dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
```

How can I have this this script run automatically at login, or possibly save these rules permanently for my sisters computer? Could you please provide some detailed code, as my first attempts at rc.local method and iptables-save have not been very successful. On every reboot, all INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD chains are reset to ACCEPT, with no policies listed when I type `sudo iptables -L -v`

Comment: Almost two years later, but an important comment: make sure that you have `ip6tables` rules if you get v6 connectivity one day, since IPv6 is handled by `ip6tables` and not `iptables`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You may want to use the `iptables-persistent` package rather than mess with your boot scripts.  First, run your script to set up the firewall rules.  Secondly, run `sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`, and follow the prompts.  When it asks to save the current rules, hit "Yes" at both prompts.  Now, on reboots, your iptables rules will be restored.

---

***NOTE:*** If you change your rules after this, you will need to do the following command(s) after the changes:

To save your IPv4 iptables rules: `sudo su -c 'iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4'`

To save your IPv6 ip6tables rules: `sudo su -c 'ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6'`

Comment: Thank You, that worked. If I do want to temporarily change the rules, I can just run a script from the terminal yes?

Comment: Yes, or you can directly manipulate the iptables system directly.  HOWEVER, if you plan on using the temporary rule persistently, the new rule(s) aren't guaranteed to be saved unless you do the commands I state in my answer.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent` after changing a rule.

Comment: @souravc the question that responds to that is "Why would you need or want to?"  The idea is that you wouldn't have to and can just rewrite (or overwrite( the `rules.v4` or `rules.v6` files manually so they get indexed at next boot, or immediately if you run `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` or `ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the firewall rules in:

```
/etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Perhaps the most obvious answer will be to create a file called iptables in:

```
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d
```

with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

and make it executable using

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

This way before your network interface is activated your rules will be loaded.

Comment: Thank you, does it throw log anywhere? This isn't working and I suspect this is due to my dns server used has a resolver not yet started when my host is booting.

Comment: This also doesnt' work for me. I always thought this was the way but someone pointed out my firewall wasn't up.

Comment: Have you tried to run it manually?
`sudo /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules`
what was the resulting message?