# VPN between two ubuntu 14.04.3 servers

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have a Server at home which has an Ipv6 but no ipv4 (because my provider uses DS-Lite). I also got a vServer wich has an static ipv4. Now I would like to setup a vpn service on both servers and route all traffic from my home server thought the vserver and also that all connections that connect to the vserver get send to my home server. That way I want to be able to get a ipv4 for my home server, because I already ran into some problems with ipv6 and some applications/servers. For example Teamspeak. I have heard about OpenVPN, I tried setting it up but I have no clue what I am doing and I couldn't find any helpful sites in the internet. I don't need to use OpenVPN, I just don't know anything else. If someone can guide me through this, I really would appreciate it. A step by step Guide would be amazing.

Thanks in advanced
xF4m3

Comment: This is an excellent tutorial, I used it to set mine up. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

[Follow this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

For the server part make sure you are using the Ubuntu server with the static ipv4 address.

If digital ocean's is having problems then try replacing their .conf contents with the one down below.

```
mode server
port 1134
proto tcp6-server
dev tap
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 32
verb 15
mute 10
user nobody
group nogroup
```

Skip the client configuration part on digital ocean if you will be connecting through the CLI and use the one from Linux.com

[Config Linux Clients to connect to OpenVPN Server through CLI](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/459675:configure-linux-clients-to-connect-to-openvpn-server)

Comment: Okay so i did all this, but how can i route all incoming traffic (in the ipv4 vserver) to my ipv6 home server? So the client trying to connec tto the vserver gets connected to my home server , but the client should only knoew the ipv4 (because some services dont use ipv6 yet) all traffic that can use ipv6 can go directly to my home server.

Comment: Hopefully this helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/462533/route-all-traffic-through-openvpn

Comment: These guys on the openvpn forums seem to be trying the same thing. https://forums.openvpn.net/topic11877.html